# Recover password css not linking

Tags: html, css

So part of the website I am building requires a password reset. I have written and implemented it correctly and it works. However, it uses a random token after the url (urlhere/reset/"random token") which is preventing me from properly linking the css in the website header (used as an inclusion on pages). I have also just tried directly using the link rel on the resets html page directly and that does not work. 
TL;DR - I am looking for a way for any path that is (urlhere/reset/anything) to use a css file,

```
    <%
    if (page === "/reset/:token") { %>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/reset.css">
    <% } %>
```

Comment: Is the path to the css file correct? In your browser go to the developer option's console and check if you are getting any 404 error.

Comment: what language is your `<% if ()...`? That isn't html/css.

Comment: @Michael Coker NodeJS I think ;)

Comment: @Muhammad it is node js yes. The path to the css file is correct I believe the problem is with :token aspect of it but i am not sure what to do about it

Comment: It isn't node js (which isn't a language for a start). It looks like EJS.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the URL of your stylesheet is `/static/css/reset.css` and not `/reset/static/css/reset.css`.

Add the missing `/` to the URL.

Comment: Have you tested loading that URL directly? Does it give the expected content-type? With the expected content-type request header? Have you checked in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools to make sure the URL being requested in the one you expect?